# How to compare dictonary key with xml attribute value in xml using LINQ in c #?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i've a dictonary " dictSample " which contains

```
1 data1
2 data2
3 data3
4 data4
```

and an xml file"sample.xml" in the form of:

```
<node>
 <element id="1" value="val1"/>
 <element id="2" value="val2"/>
 <element id="3" value="val3"/>
 <element id="4" value="val4"/>
 <element id="5" value="val5"/>
 <element id="6" value="val6"/>
 <element id="7" value="val7"/>
</node>
```

i need to match the dictonary keys with the xml attribute id and to insert the matching id and 
the value of attribute"value" into another dictonary

now i'm using like:

```
XmlDocument XDOC = new XmlDocument();
XDOC.Load("Sample.xml");
XmlNodeList NodeList = XDOC.SelectNodes("//element");
Dictionary<string, string> dictTwo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string l_strIndex in dictSample .Keys)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode XNode in NodeList)
            {
                XmlElement XEle = (XmlElement)XNode;
                if (dictSample[l_strIndex] == XEle.GetAttribute("id"))
                    dictTwo.Add(dictSample[l_strIndex], XEle.GetAttribute("value").ToString());
            }
        }
```

please help me to do this in a simple way using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dictonary<string,string> dict2=new Dictonary<string,string>()
    XDocument XDOC=XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
    dict2=(from key in dictSample from element in XDOC.Descendants("element") where
           key.Value == element.Attribute("id").Value select new { ID = 
           element.Attribute("id").Value,Val = element.Attribute
           ("value").Value}).ToDictionary(X => X.ID, X => X.Val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
var q = from x in NodeList.Cast<XmlElement>()
    join k in dictSample on x.GetAttribute("id") equals k.Value
    select new { Key = k.Value, Value = x.GetAttribute("value").ToString() };

dictTwo = q.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```